# Adding elements to the collection through DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I bounded DataGridView control to the List collection. So, I can edit elements of the collection. Is there any way to enable removing and adding elements to the collection using this grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic `List<T>` does not fully support binding to the `DataGridView`, as you can see you can edit items in the list but not add or remove.

What you need to use is either a `BindingList<T>` or a `BindingSource`.

The `BindingList<T>` will allow you to use the UI to add and delete rows from the grid - when you change you `DataSource` to this you will see the blank new row at the botton of the grid. You still cannot programatically add or remove rows. For that you need a `BindingSource`.

An example of both is below (using an example Users class, but the detail of that isn't important here).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<User> usersList;
    private BindingSource source;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        usersList = new List<User>();
        usersList.Add(new User { PhoneID = 1, Name = "Fred" });
        usersList.Add(new User { PhoneID = 2, Name = "Tom" });

        // You can construct your BindingList<User> from the List<User>
        BindingList<User> users = new BindingList<User>(usersList);

        // This line binds to the BindingList<User>
        dataGridView1.DataSource = users;

        // We now create the BindingSource
        source = new BindingSource();

        // And assign the List<User> as its DataSource
        source.DataSource = usersList;

        // And again, set the DataSource of the DataGridView
        // Note that this is just example code, and the BindingList<User>
        // DataSource setting is gone. You wouldn't do this in the real world 
        dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;               

    }

    // This button click event handler shows how to add a new row, and
    // get at the inserted object to change its values.
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        User user = (User)source.AddNew();
        user.Name = "Mary Poppins";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Your answer and explanations rocks. That's what I wanted. I used BindingList<T> as a source collection. And I can add add and remove records. But I can not see any UI from the grid. Is there any display it?

Comment: @Peter17 by UI I simply meant that with BindingList<T> bound to the grid you can now add and remove items in the list by using the grid itself.

Answer (score 2):

There are [OnUserAddedRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.onuseraddedrow.aspx) and [OnUserDeletedRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.onuserdeletedrow.aspx) events that you can subscribe to so that you could modify your collection on user action.

Comment: Thank you. But there is no any empty row on the bottoms of the DataGridView, despite the fact that AllowUserAddRows set to true.

Comment: Is it possible at all to add rows through bounded DataGridView? Or should I use something else to achieve this goal?

Comment: The example on the MSDN has 2 buttons for adding and deleting rows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx

Comment: I tried that, but I got an error: "Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.